# node.js: How can I know a debugger is connected to my process?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to know, from within my code, if running in a debug environment. I could go over the node command-line arguments (`process.execArgv`) and look for `--debug` or `--debug-brk`, but I'm hoping there's a cleverer way of finding this out.

Any ideas?