# How to know if a nodejs process has the debugger already attached to the process and not just listening to it (debug mode)?

Tags: node.js, debugging

I was expecting to have a simple answer to this question but I was unable to find it.

It is a bit different if we are in debug mode (the process started with --inspect) than that if the process has the debugger already attached to it, so that any "debugger" instruction will just halt the process.

Similar questions were asked, I found these ones:

[How to programmatically detect debug mode in nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889470/how-to-programmatically-detect-debug-mode-in-nodejs)

But the provided (selected) solution do not longer work for recent versions of node. And I think that the question was not exactly the same.

[node.js: How can I know a debugger is connected to my process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231155/node-js-how-can-i-know-a-debugger-is-connected-to-my-process?noredirect=1&lq=1)

This looked like to be the right one! but....I think it was closed by error many years ago because points to the previous one :-(

So I apologize if I have not digged enough in stack overflow but this question remains without a simple answer for me.

I was expecting a core method something like: inspector.isDebuggerAttached()